# Create a cover for my thesis

Tags: covers

I woould like to make a cover for my thesis with latex. It should look like the following, which I mane with MS Word:

[image]

I only know the commands:

```
\title{...}
\author{...}
\date{...}
```

But don't know how to get my thing... Can somobody help me with that?

Comment: Take a look at the `titling` package. That makes this stuff pretty easy and is well-documented. It does depend on your class etc., though, so if you need further help, please post a Minimum Working Example showing what you've tried and your basic document set up.

Comment: Although ``titling`` is a useful package, its documentation is a very hard read to novice users of LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the class you're using, here's an attempt.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % showframe is just for the example

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{margin=3cm}
\centering

\vspace*{\stretch{2}}

\Large The Title of my Thesis

\vspace{\stretch{1}}

\normalsize The duration: 12 weeks

\vspace{\stretch{0.5}}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Submission date & xx.yy.zzzz \\[2ex]
Student's name  & Name \\[2ex]
From            & Place
\end{tabular}

\vspace{\stretch{3}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{}}
My name & My professor's name \\[2ex]
        & My supervisor's name
\end{tabular*}

\vspace{\stretch{2}}
\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry
\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\kant

\end{document}
```

The important option for `geometry` is `pass`, whereas `showframe` is just for showing that the cover page is centered on the page. If you already use `geometry`, just set its options and remove `pass`.

### A bird's eye view

[image]

### The title page

[image]

Answer (score 3):

AN example for my university:

```
\documentclass[english,ngerman,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{-3cm}
\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth+2cm][r]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{FULogoRGB(1)}} 

\vspace*{5cm}
\begin{center}
\Huge\bfseries\sffamily Die nordamerikanische Wanderratte im
Vergleich zur chinesischen.

\vspace*{2cm}
\large 
von

Herbert Voß
\end{center}

\enlargethispage{3cm}
\vfill
\parbox[t]{0.45\textwidth}{%
    Matrikelnummer: 1234572              \\
    Fachbereich: Biologie und  Pharmazie \\
    Institut: Insekten                   \\
    \today
  }%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%{\raggedleft%
Gutachter:\\
  Prof. A.\,Krachulke\\
  Dr. M.\,Schnasebeutel
\end{tabular}
%}%
\end{titlepage}

foo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
\documentclass[13pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{array}{\setlength{\arraycolsep}{50pt}} % This controls the distance between the columns
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} 
%\hrule\vspace{0.025truein}\hrule %Decorative lines. Might work..
\begin{center}
\vspace{0.3truein}
{\large Title of the thesis}\\
\vspace{2truein}
{\large The duration: 12 weeks}\\
\vspace{1.5truein}
\[
\begin{array}{ll}
\mbox{Submission date} & \mbox{xx.yy.zz}\\
\mbox{Student's name} & \mbox{Name}\\
\mbox{From} & \mbox{Place of birth}
\end{array}
\]
\vspace{6cm}
\[
\begin{array}{ll}
\mbox{My name} & \mbox{My professor's name}\\
& \mbox{My supervisor's name}
\end{array}
\]
\end{center}
%\hrule\vspace{0.025truein}\hrule %Decorative lines. Might work..
\end{document}
```

It will give you this:

[image]

Hope it works for your needs. Greetings!

Comment: The `13pt` option has no effect, did you mean `12pt`? Also, I wouldn't set the `arraycolsep` for *all* `array`s, what if he uses that environment elsewhere? Instead of using math mode, I would use two `tabular`s and add `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{50pt}` before the first. The `center` environment will localise that change, so it doesn't effect tables later in the document.

Comment: Nice suggestions. You're right. It's easier and nicer that way. Greetings.